# How do I test In-App Purchase in iOS 12 using sandbox account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am no longer able to test In-App Purchases with Simulator for iOS 12. I didn't have this problem before.

The instructions say for me to log out of iTunes and App Store in Settings, and when I test the In-App Purchase, iOS would ask me for an Apple ID. I have done that, but iOS never asks for an Apple ID. Instead I get an error object in my code that says "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". (It doesn't terminate the app. I was able to successfully print the description of the error object in the debug window.)

When I try to put my sandbox account in the iTunes and App Store account setting, I get a message that says, "There was a problem connecting to the server."

Answer (score 5):

You can display IAP products on both the iOS simulator as well as physical iOS devices, but to test buying or restoring purchases you've always needed a physical device.

On iOS 12, you can set a default sandbox user in `Settings -> Your Account -> iTunes & App Store -> Sandbox Account`. This can help out with the sign in prompts and save your phone from having to change accounts repeatedly.

Comment: I don't believe your first statement is correct. I've been able to actually make purchases as well as restore purchases using Simulator with a sandbox account. Are you saying I can no longer do that in iOS 12?

Comment: That's strange I've never been able to make purchases from Simulator maybe there were changes at some point. I'm trying to find some official Apple documentation on it but they never mention it outright.